# jFreeChart: How to draw the y-axis in a line chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

With Java, is there any way of drawing the y-axis in a line chart with [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info)?

I need to show both the x-axis and the y-axis, and I already draw the x-axis with the flowing code:

```
LineFunction2D x_axis = new LineFunction2D(0, 0);  
XYDataset xdataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(
    x_axis, min_x-min_x/15, max_x+max_x/15, 100, "X-Axis");
xyplot.setDataset(1, xdataset);
```

I think it's impossible to draw the line `x = 0` with [`LineFunction2D`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/function/LineFunction2D.html), which take the value of `a` and `b` of the equation `y = ax + b`.

Maybe there is a function to call to show the axis because I have seen a demo showing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in the XYPlot class:

```
public void setDomainZeroBaselineVisible(boolean visible);
```

...that will show a line at the zero value on the domain (x) axis.

Answer (score 1):

`Y=aX+b` can be displayed using `ChartFactory.createLineChart`. This way, you get your series, the X and Y axis in one go.

Comment: +1 good idea; the source of `ChartFactory` has good examples of how to construct custom charts.